# Postgis dissolve boundaries and calculate mean values

Tags: postgis, st, st-union, collect

I like to combine two layers and calculate/summarize data from one to another. So, I have values for the subtypes (yellow lines) and the area of the subtypes. Now I like to calculate a mean value for the whole block (bb in green). i.e. I have values for green volume gv for each of the subtypes and I like to calculate the mean gv value for the whole block. I tried like following:

```
round(avg(gv*subtype_area/bb_area),2) as gv,
```

Afterwards the result should be only the geometry of the green geometry with the mean values.
My attempt was:

```
select max(gid) as gid, max(bb_area) as bb_area,
round(avg(gv*subtype_area/bb_area),2) as gv,
st_union(geom) as geom
from table_btk
group by geom;
```

But I still got the geom of the the subtypes. Also not working when using ST_collect instead.
can anybody help?

[image: green area block, yellow lines subtypes]

Comment: It is unclear if there are indeed "*two layers*" as in *two tables*, or if there is any attribute in `table_btk` that denotes a subtypes membership to a block. Please add more details about your data set(s).

Comment: oh yes, sorry. Both is available. I have for all features in btk a column with the block number bb. So the idea was to "dissolve the many geometries to one block geom . I have also a bb_table with the geometry and it could be possible to join and take this geom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tow options:

- `JOIN` both tables and aggregate over the `bb_table` entries:

  ```
  SELECT
    bb.<id>,
    ROUND(AVG(btk.gv*btk.subtype_area/btk.bb_area), 2) AS gv,
    ...,
    bb.geom
  FROM
    bb_table AS bb
    JOIN
    btk_table AS btk
      ON bb.<id> = btk.<bb_id>
  GROUP BY
    bb.<id>, bb.geom
  ;
  ```

  or, potentially faster:

  ```
  SELECT
    bb.<id>,
    gt.*,
    bb.geom
  FROM
    bb_table AS bb
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        ROUND(AVG(btk.gv*btk.subtype_area/btk.bb_area), 2) AS gv,
        ...
      FROM
        btk_table AS btk
      WHERE
        btk.<bb_id> = bb.<id>
    ) AS gt
  ;
  ```
- (correctly) `ST_Union` the `btk_table` geometries by the `<bb_id>` column:

  ```
  SELECT
    <bb_id>,
    ROUND(AVG(gv*subtype_area/bb_area), 2) AS gv,
    ...,
    ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM
    btk_table
  GROUP BY
    <bb_id>
  ;
  ```

---

The `JOIN` approaches should be faster when dealing with many `subtype` geometries per `<bb_id>` - avoiding a comparably costly geometric union.

In any way, make sure you have an index `ON btk_table (<bb_id>)`.